# Binding classes issue with AlpineJS - ternary operator and curly brackets

Tags: alpine.js

EDIT: Due to the general syntax of AlpineJS, writing a ternary operator inside curly brackets is a mistake you may easily run into.

---

This is just a "grammar" issue but I really want to figure it out... Let's jump into it.

Everything is ok if I write:

```
:class="{ 'some_class': activeSlide == slide }"
```

On the contrary it doesn't work (i.e. 'some_class' is not added as a class) if I write:

```
:class="{ activeSlide == slide ? 'some_class' : '' }"
```

What's wrong with it?

(I don't think it's relevant, but you can have a look at the entire code here, inside 'template' tags: [link](https://codebase-frontend-library.github.io/codebase-4/docs/8-alpinejs-components/alpinejs-slideshows/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator works only with the [non-object class syntax](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#binding-classes):

```
:class="activeSlide == slide ? 'some_class' : ''"
```

You can use the [shorthand conditionals](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#shorthand-conditionals) as well:

```
:class="activeSlide == slide && 'some_class'"
```